# Turning variable contents into line of code

Tags: python, oop

Say I want to make it so that when I write:

```
class Bacon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bacon = True
    def eatBacon(self):
        self.bacon = False
        print self.bacon

bacon = Bacon()
x = bacon

y = raw_input("eatBacon")
```

And then say I want to do something like this:

```
x.y()
```

Is that possible?

Sorry if it might seem like a dumb question, I am just beginning to learn object oriented programming.

Edit:
Say I enter "eatBacon" as input.
I want x.y() to translate to bacon.eatBacon()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What is the value of `x` and `y` in your example?  You might be looking for the `getattr` function.

Comment: hmm , do you want to execute `x.raw_input("eatBacon")`there or what do you mean?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you've written it `x.y()` will just raise an exception.  Do you want to run `eatBacon` when the user enters something?

Comment: Question is unclear and not sure what you are trying to do with your class. please re-iterate it ?

Comment: Yes Gjordis and aquavitae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but not exactly like that.

In Python, functions are just like any other variable so you can assign them just like you would any other variable.  Exploiting this, you can have code like this:

```
def eat_bacon():
    return 'Om nom nom.'

call_map = {'eat': eat_bacon} # here, I am using the name of method

y = raw_input('Type eat: ')
print call_map[y]()
```

However, when you have an object its a bit different. You can fetch attributes of objects with `getattr` method, and you would use that thus:

```
class OmNom(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.bacon = True
  def eat(self):
     self.bacon = False
     return 'Om nom nom'

monster = OmNom()
y = raw_input('Type eat: ')
print getattr(monster, y)()
# This is the same as
# z = getattr(monster, 'eat')
# Now z points to the eat method of the object, then
# z() will call that method.
```

Comment: Is this recommended in a CLI app environment? Or should conditionals check the input and call the corresponding functions? I wanted to implement this into a program I'm working on but it seems like there are security risks like calling functions that shouldn't be called. Is it worth it to save many lines of conditional statements?

Comment: If the user enters a name that doesn't exist, the application will simply raise an exception. In the first example, it will be a `KeyError` and the second example will raise `AttributeError`. You can also have a list of "callables" so that only certain attributes/methods can be called and have one membership check instead of a large conditional tree.

Comment: That's true. One other question. Say you wanted to make the method calls inside of the OmNom class and call OmNom's methods. Would you still use `getattr` or would you use the dictionary call version?

Comment: You can use `getattr` with `self` as the first argument or `__dict__`, but I am curious why you would need this inside your class.

Comment: Not necessary, obviously, just curious as I have an input handler class that calls sub handlers within that class based on input. Because of certain instance variables it is most convenient in my case to use it in the same class, but not necessary

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is

```
method = getattr(x, y)
method()
```

getattr is fairly versatile, and can be used in many other places where you need to fetch an attribute of an object by name. See [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/getattr.html) for more details.

Comment: i don't think he is trying to access his method using 'name'.

Comment: The example, where he wants the user to enter the string 'eatBacon', and have his script call bacon.eatBacon(), suggests that he is. Why do you think this is not the case?

Comment: ya thats the same i feel now.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
 x.__dict__[y]()
```

Every object in python has __ dict __ which gives introspection and access to all the methods of the class as dict.
And in general, everything in python is a dict.

Comment: _And in general, everything in python is a dict._? I think you mean _object_ not _dict_.

Comment: It's good to know about __dict__, but using getattr is better. As a general rule, double-underscore attributes and methods shouldn't be used directly.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid and what are the objects made of? What data structure is used to store and manage objects? Everything in python is stored as a dictionary, and this is how the perception of objects is achieved.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, you can infer it from the statement " Most namespaces are currently implemented as Python dictionaries" in http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: That's a very generous stretching of the statement, in any case this statement _"Every object in python has `__dict__`"_ is not true.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Bacon:                                                                                                                                                                                               
      def __init__(self):
          self.bacon = True
      def eatBacon(self):
          self.bacon = False
          print self.bacon

  bacon = Bacon()
  x = bacon

  y = raw_input("eatBacon: ")

  if hasattr(x, y):
      print getattr(x, y)()
  else:
      print 'Method not found: %s' % str(y)
```

Output:

```
eatBacon: eatBacon
False
None
```